# Delete photo from parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would want to delete a photo from parse.  How can I do that?It looks like an easy thing but I can't do and there aren't really sources that show how to do it. This is my save code. I am saving to a class called Topc.

```
- (void)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData
{
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"TopsImage.jpg" data:imageData];

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    // Set determinate mode
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Uploading";
    [HUD show:YES];

    // Save PFFile
    [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //Hide determinate HUD
            [HUD hide:YES];

            // Show checkmark
            HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
            [self.view addSubview:HUD];

            // The sample image is based on the work by http://www.pixelpressicons.com, http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/ca/
            // Make the customViews 37 by 37 pixels for best results (those are the bounds of the build-in progress indicators)
            HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]];

            // Set custom view mode
            HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

            HUD.delegate = self;

            // Create a PFObject around a PFFile and associate it with the current user
            PFObject *userPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Topc"];
            [userPhoto setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

            // Set the access control list to current user for security purposes
            userPhoto.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [userPhoto setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

            [userPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    [self refresh:nil];
                }
                else{
                    // Log details of the failure
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
        else{
            [HUD hide:YES];
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
        // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
        HUD.progress = (float)percentDone/100;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a category on PFFile that allows you to update a file, which means delete the old file then upload the new one with a same name. I originally thought replacing the file in the associated object would remove the old one, but it didn't as my data usage was oddly increasing.

```
+(void)updateFileWithName:(NSString*)name data:(NSData*)imageData completion:(void(^)(PFFile* file))completion
{
NSString* endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://api.parse.com/1/files/%@", name];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:endpoint];
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
[req setValue:kParseApplicationKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
[req setValue:kParseMasterKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Master-Key"];

NSLog(@"Updating file: %@", name);
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           NSLog(@"Deleted old file");
                           PFFile* file = [PFFile fileWithName:name data:imageData];
                           [file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Saved new file");
                               completion(file);
                           }];

                       }];
}
```

You can easily change this to solely delete the file by removing the the block in the `NSURLConnection` completion handler

Comment: Be careful when You pass your Master Key through request!

Answer (score 1):

[ParsePhotoPFObject deleteEventually];

Answer (score 0):

For deleting image or a complete row firstly you will need to fire a **query** to get it from your Parse db ,something like below :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Topc"];

[query whereKeyExists:@"imageFile"];   //Change this condition to fetch the row.

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", object);

     //This might work as I searched for this deleting image but there is no method to do so.
     //So a way would be is to get that object and then setting nil value in it's place.
     //Else if u want to delete the entire row then u could simply type, [object deleteInBackground]
        object[@"imageFile"] = [NSNull null];  
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Also ,You can [follow below link for deleting PFFILE](http://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-delete-a-file)

Comment: Could you explain more please ?
Here we have the class "Topc" with a row named "imageFile" for name "TopsImage".
How do you delete or clear only this column ? Thanks

Comment: To clear I suggest :
[parseObject setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"imageFile"];

Comment: @JordanMontel do check my post ,I have updated that !.. let me know if any doubt.

Comment: @Nanoxx Did you find this answer useful or not. If yes then do tick and vote up, would be appreciated !

Answer (score -2):

In your code, you add an image in two steps:

1. Upload a PFFile (the JPG file)
2. Create a userPhoto (TopC) object that points to the PFFile in step 1

You don't state what you mean by "delete", so you have two options:

- Only delete the userPhoto object, and keep the file

or

- Delete both the userPhoto object AND the file

If you want to keep the file for later use, you just call deleteInBackground on the userPhoto class.

If you want to delete both, you should start by deleting the file with deleteInBackgroundWithBlock, and then in the block, if successful, you delete the userPhoto:

```
PFFile *imageFile = userPhoto[@"imageFile"];

[imageFile deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (succeeded) {
    // Successfully deleted the image file. Now delete userPhoto:
    [userPhoto deleteInBackground];

  }
}];
```

Comment: here is link to [PFFile](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html) where is deleteInBackground method.

Comment: PFFile does not have a deleteInBackground method

Comment: @LilMoke it did 5 years ago when this answer was posted

Comment: LOL, I figured that might the case.   Do you know of any way to delete the PFFile today?  It is actually kind of crazy that a delete feature was removed.

Comment: @LilMoke Sorry, no. I haven't used parse in years. Hope you'll find a solution

Comment: Yes, I am sure I will... thanks for the reply on such an old post!!